# Concating string variable in array of strings

Tags: reactjs

i have an array of strings and a variable of type string and when i press on the button Next which is in the Step Wizard form i want to concat that Variable to the Array using a callback function from child to parent component the problem is that it's not working as i want it to be it keeps adding that same variable again and again even i did an if statement i didn't know what to do to solve it

the parent component function

```
  myCallback = () => {

    if (this.state.modules.includes(this.state.moduleTitle)) {

        this.setState({ modules: this.state.modules });
    }
    //works fine when there are no modules
    if (this.state.moduleTitle == "") {
        this.setState({ modules: this.state.modules });
    }
    else {

        this.setState({ modules: this.state.modules.concat(this.state.moduleTitle) })
    }

}
```

the " moduleTitle " is that string variable and " modules " is the array of strings

the child component

```
continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
   // this.setState({ value: "full" });
    this.props.callbackFromParent();
    this.props.nextStep();

}
```

the continue function is used to go to the next step of the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is to pass the new `moduleTitle` back via your callback:

```
continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentTitle = this.props.title // or whatever your prop is called
    this.props.callbackFromParent(currentTitle);
    this.props.nextStep();
}
```

and deal with it at the other end:

```
myCallback = newModuleTitle => {
  const currentModules = this.state.modules
  if (newModuleTitle !== '' && !currentModules.includes(newModuleTitle)) {
    this.setState({ modules: [...currentModules, newModuleTitle] })
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't get your question about the current title if it's from state or event

Comment: where is the moduleTitle? In the state, props, or on the button?

Comment: it's in the state of the parent component and i passed it as a props to the child

Comment: it's still the same problem when i press Next it's fine and when i go back and press again next it adds the newModuleTitle again despite i have that first if statement but it's not working

Comment: Ok, although you *could* just use the state in the parent, it's better practice to pass the data back with the click event, so that changes are treated as single atomic entities.

Comment: just to be sure about that CallBack function is my code fine because at first am testing to not add the same string so i just set the the old array with it's old values and second if the string var is empty it won't be added and last if it's not existing it adds it

Comment: you don't need to re-set the state if there's no changes, I've updated the callback to simplify it.

Comment: thank you a lot man for your help and sorry if i wasted your time , it finally worked as i wanted again thank you so much for your support